# Algorithm negotiation fail error when using SharpSSH

Tags: sharpssh

Problem:
When i try to connect by sharpssh catch this error Algorithm negotiation fail

I generate public key and ssh-2 RSA private Key with password. Then export to OpenSSHH and use it to connect

To connect i tried:

```
if (input.IdentityFile != null) sshCp.AddIdentityFile(input.IdentityFile, "123456");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method "AddIdentityFile" needs a path string to your private key file. Try:

```
if (input.IdentityFile != null)
    sshCp.AddIdentityFile("path", "123456");
```